# Order of cyclic subgroup equal to order of generator

Tags: group-theory

I'm stuck on a very simple proof and it is driving me up the wall. I'm supposed to show equivalence of the two definitions of order of a group element $a \in G$, $G$ finite, that is, 1) the order of the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$ equals $m$, and 2) $o(a) = m$, where $m$ is the smallest integer such that $a^{m}=e$.

My attempt at showing $|<a>| = m \implies m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^{m} = e$:

The only thing I can really work with is that $<a> = \{a^{i} | i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, so certainly the set $\{e,a,a^{2},...,a^{m-1}\}$$\subset$ $<a>$, and furthermore we can require that each $a^{j} \in \{e,a,a^{2},...,a^{m-1}\}$ is distinct (i.e. no $a^{j} = a^{n}$ unless $j\equiv n$, $mod$ $m$), and that the set size is $m$. Then, $a^{m}$ must be somewhere in the list, so by the division algorithm, $m = pq +r$, $0 \leq r < p$, so $p|(m-r)$.

Here is where I'm stuck, because I know that $m=0=r=p$, but I've been thinking about this for so long that I am at a standstill. After I can figure out a way to show that, I have that for some arbitrary $a^{k} \in$ $<a>$, $a^{k} = a^{mq+r} = (a^{m})^{q}a^{r}=e^{q}a^{r}=a^{r}$, so $<a>$ $\subset$ $\{e,a,a^{2},...,a^{m-1}\}$, and so $<a>$ $=$ $\{e,a,a^{2},...,a^{m-1}\}$. Then $a^{m} = e$, and $m$ is the smallest such integer that this happens for.

Any hints or criticism would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is easier to prove by contradiction. Suppose that there exists $n<m$ such that $a^{n}=e$.  What does this imply about the order of the subgroup generated by $a$?

Comment: It implies that it is smaller than m, but how do I show that?

Comment: Suppose that there exists some element $\alpha \in \langle a \rangle$ such that $\alpha$ is given by $\alpha = a^{k}$ for some minimal $k>n$.